# How to add index values of array in object to a key

Tags: javascript

I have an object in variable `info` as :

```
0: {ProId: "Space", Name: "cake", Quantity: 1}
1: {ProId: "new", Name: "walk", Quantity: 1}
```

I am trying to change the Quantity value to it's `index+1` for each index ,

I have tried to have a static value as:

```
  for (var key in obj){
    var value= obj[key];
    value['Quantity'] = 5;
  }
```

Expected O/p:

```
console.log(info)
    0: {ProId: "Space", Name: "cake", Quantity: 1}
    1: {ProId: "new", Name: "walk", Quantity: 2}
    2: {............................Quantity: 3}.....
```

But May I know how can I have the `Quantity` value as above mentioned

Comment: Please share the expected output also.

Comment: why do you have an object instead of an array?

Comment: You'd be better using an array to store these as there's no guarantee of object ordering being consistent.

Comment: @palaѕн I have added expected O/P ....

Comment: @net.uk.sweet I didn't knew that , sorry , how can I do that instead ?

Comment: Is info an array?

Comment: @net.uk.sweet when i console.log i got the above way .....

Comment: I'm probably guessing it here but I believe info is an Array as console.log on an array is formatted the way author has formatted on his post


@Codenewbie what is the result of `console.log(Array.isArray(info))` ?

Comment: @VidushanChooriyakumaran true

Comment: So, your variable `info` is indeed an Array. You can have a look at the solutions below suggesting to loop through it with [Array.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) or [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: @VidushanChooriyakumaran oh no , i really misguided all with my confused data above .....i feel so bad! thanks mate for letting me know that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some hints:

- Take an array instead of an object, if you need an easy iterable data structure. This gives control over the iteration order, too.
- Use numbers for numeric values. If you need later a (formatted) string apply `toString` to it.

For getting a new value of a property, you could mutate the given data.

Using:

- [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) for visiting all items of the array,
- an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), a short form of a function.

```js
var array = [{ ProId: "Space", Name: "cake", Quantity: "1" }, { ProId: "new", Name: "walk", Quantity: "1" }];

array.forEach((object, i) => object.Quantity = i + 1);

console.log(array);
```

Or get new objects by mapping the array.

Using:

- [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) for getting a new array,
- [spread syntax `...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) for taking all properties of an object into a new object

```js
var array = [{ ProId: "Space", Name: "cake", Quantity: "1" }, { ProId: "new", Name: "walk", Quantity: "1" }],
    newArray = array.map((object, i) => ({ ...object, Quantity: i + 1 }));

console.log(newArray);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can map the array and return a new array but merging the old object with new object with updated `Quantity` value like:

```js
const data = [{ProId: "Space", Name: "cake", Quantity: "1"}, {ProId: "new", Name: "walk", Quantity: "1"}],
  updatedData = data.map((x, i)=> ({...x, Quantity: ++i}));
 
console.log(updatedData)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

A simple example of updating an object key value (which is done here inside the `map()` method) is like:

```js
let obj = { a: 0, b: 0};
let newObj = { ...obj, a: 1 };

console.log( newObj )
```

Comment: can you try giving some explanations of what's going on please

Comment: But I have the data as I mentioned , not the above way you mentioned

Comment: How you have the data like? Can you share the actual data format, not the console log view?

Answer (score 1):

Use [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) with `index` and add `Quantity` at certain index `+` `index`. And use `toString()` method as you want to have values in `String` format.

```js
var obj = [{ProId: "Space", Name: "cake", Quantity: "1"}, {ProId: "new", Name: "walk", Quantity: "1"}]
obj.forEach(function(el,idx){
  el.Quantity=(idx+parseInt(el.Quantity)).toString()
})
console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using:

```
let obj = {
 '0': {ProId: "Space", Name: "cake", Quantity: "1"},
 '1': {ProId: "new", Name: "walk", Quantity: "1"}
}
for(key in obj) {
   let qty = String(Number(obj[key]['Quantity'])+Number(key))
   obj[key]['Quantity'] = qrt;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One way is to `map` your current array.

```js
const info2 = info.map((product, index) => ({ ...product, Quantity: index + 1 }));
```

In case you want `Quantity` as a string do this `Quantity: index + 1 + ''`, or `Quantity: (index + 1).toString()`. Whatever suits you.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this:

```js
let info = {
  0: {
    ProId: "Space",
    Name: "cake",
    Quantity: "1"
  },
  1: {
    ProId: "new",
    Name: "walk",
    Quantity: "1"
  }
}

let index = 1;
Object.values(info).map(function(val) {
  val.Quantity = index;
  index++;
});

console.log(info);
```

Answer (score 1):

I made it in the case you are using just the object, without set up as an array.

```js
let info = {
    0: { ProId: "Space", Name: "cake", Quantity: "1" },
    1: { ProId: "new", Name: "walk", Quantity: "2" },
    2: { ProId: "foo", Name: "bar", Quantity: "3" }
}

function incrementQuantify(obj) {
    let _newInfo = {};

    for (const key of Object.keys(obj)) {
        info[key].Quantity = parseInt(info[key].Quantity, 10) + 1;
        _newInfo[key] = info[key];
    }

    return _newInfo;
}
/*
{
  '0': { ProId: 'Space', Name: 'cake', Quantity: 2 },
  '1': { ProId: 'new', Name: 'walk', Quantity: 3 },
  '2': { ProId: 'foo', Name: 'bar', Quantity: 4 }
}
*/
console.log(incrementQuantify(info));
```

Shorter way:

```js
let info = { 0: { ProId: "Space", Name: "cake", Quantity: "1" }, 1: { ProId: "new", Name: "walk", Quantity: "2" }, 2: { ProId: "foo", Name: "bar", Quantity: "3" } }
for (const key of Object.keys(info)) info[key].Quantity = parseInt(info[key].Quantity, 10) + 1;
console.log(info);
```

`edit: I already made an way to work with arrays too!`

```js
let info = [
    { ProId: "Space", Name: "cake", Quantity: "1" },
    { ProId: "new", Name: "walk", Quantity: "2" },
    { ProId: "foo", Name: "bar", Quantity: "3" }
]

function incrementQuantify(obj) {
    let newObj = obj;
    newObj.Quantity = parseInt(obj.Quantity, 10) + 1;
    return newObj;
}
info.map(incrementQuantify);
/*
[
  { ProId: 'Space', Name: 'cake', Quantity: 2 },
  { ProId: 'new', Name: 'walk', Quantity: 3 },
  { ProId: 'foo', Name: 'bar', Quantity: 4 }
]
*/
console.log(info);
```

Shorter way:

```js
let info = [ { ProId: "Space", Name: "cake", Quantity: "1" }, { ProId: "new", Name: "walk", Quantity: "2" }, { ProId: "foo", Name: "bar", Quantity: "3" } ]; info.map(o => o.Quantity = parseInt(o.Quantity, 10) + 1);
console.log(info);
```

Hope it helps!